# Send setTimeout name, element id, and time as parameters of a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, settimeout

This is probably something really obvious, but I've searched around and tried a few things, and can't get it to work, so maybe someone can point out my error here.

I have a setTimeout that I will end up using over and over (and I know there is the setinterval, but I actually need to control when the timer starts and stops, and whether it starts again each time).  Anyway, I figured if I'm writing it over and over, I should be able to use a function and pass it the parameters needed.

```
if ($('#selectRole').val() === 'Dispatch') {
            //show Add Notes button
            var funcAddNotesTimer = function(timerName,buttonName, timeToHide) {
                console.log(timerName);
                console.log(timeToHide / 1000);
                timerName = setTimeout(function() {
                    $('buttonName').show();
                }, timeToHide);
            };
            funcAddNotesTimer('addNotesTimer', '#disAddNotes', 30000);
```

I'm trying to set the timer function name to 'addNotesTimer', and when the timer is up I want to show the button with id #disAddNotes, and I want the timer to run for 30000 msec.

To me, what I have looks right, but I never get anything in my console log, so I don't think it's even getting into the function.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Don't create functions inside statements, create the function outside.

Comment: from what I can see there are few problmes

Comment: I you can pass a reference name like a variable - I assume `addNotesTimer` is the name of the variable to hold the timer referece

Comment: `$(buttonName).show();` buttonName is a variable so don't use it as a string literal...

Comment: but none of there would cause the console not to print

Comment: Thanks to everyone.  I moved the function outside the statement as suggested, then changed the 'buttonName' to just buttonName so it's not a string literal, and now it's working.  I was also had a dang misspelling in my if statement which was completely keeping me out of that section, and thus the code wasn't getting to that point.  Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think its possible to use a `string` argument as the name of `setTimeOut`

Heres how you could approach it

```
// var timer = null; // dont really need that

var funcAddNotesTimer = function(buttonName, timeToHide) {
                             var timerName = setTimeout(function() {
                                  //$('buttonName').show();
                                  $(buttonName).show(); // buttonName is already a string so no need to add quotes around it.
                             }, timeToHide);

                             return timerName;
                        };

 if ($('#selectRole').val() === 'Dispatch') {            
        var timer = funcAddNotesTimer('#disAddNotes', 30000);
        // do something with timer
 }
```

Comment: no the `timerName` still won't work.... the timer reference is updated to the local parameter `timerName` but that won't reflect in the passed `timer` reference

Comment: now it is the same as my comments :) also still doesn't say why the console statements are not working for the OP

Comment: interesting, running the code provided in question in console ( without if conditions ) does spits out those console lines as ```addNotesTimer``` and ```30```

Comment: @varinder You could use a string as a name of a function if you attach the function to the window as a property of it.

Comment: oh thanks - yes indeed, infact not only ```windows``` but any object for that matter, my JS is going rusty :)

Answer (score 0):

when you don't see any output in the console the reason must be something else(e.g. there is a bracket missing at the end of the code)

To set a variable with a dynamic name use the subscript-notation:

```
window[timerName] = setTimeout(/**/);
```

it will set a global variable named `addNotesTimer`.

As you currently do it you're simply overwriting the argument passed to the function.

Summary:

```
   if ($('#selectRole').val() === 'Dispatch') {
            //show Add Notes button
            var funcAddNotesTimer = function(timerName,buttonName, timeToHide) {

                console.log(timerName);
                console.log(timeToHide / 1000);
                window[timerName] = setTimeout(function() {
                    $(buttonName).show();
                }, timeToHide);
            };
            funcAddNotesTimer('addNotesTimer', '#disAddNotes', 5000);
  }
```